# Is this possible to count total times 2 variances happened in a same day in a sheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

[image]

I have a big sheet of data, I need to count all the times that 2 variable (it means the data should be non-blank) both happened in a day. I illustrated as the photo. It should go in pack 3 of columns (date, variance 1, variance 2) but it appeared many times in other columns.

So could u help by any suggestion that I can count the total?

Here is the link to the sample sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lkX0-jKirBgabZhnYgckKsABJ0LItmSPclffjWwyty0/edit#gid=0

I cannot set up the COUNTIFS to count. And I have no idea how to do.
Need to count total times that 2 variances happed in the same date.

Comment: Share the sample workbook so that we can work on that. Or share data as text table to the post. You may use `FILTER()` then `UNIQUE()` function.

Comment: which 2 variable?

Comment: @p._phidot_
I mean next to the date should always be 2 columns Cylop and Alice. If both columns next to the date are non-blank we count it as 1. Then I want to count total times of it happened all over the sheet.

Comment: @Harun24hr let me give it a try, thank you

Comment: @DuyLinh You sheet is not accessible. Please make it public.

Comment: @Harun24hr yeah, I've made it public. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Let try it `=COUNTA(FILTER($H$7:$H,$H$7:$H=F8,$I$7:$I<>"",$J$7:$J<>""))`.

Comment: @Harun24hr Thank you, but it only count H I J, what is about from K to S? The file is the demo, the data would be spread in many columns

Comment: I am little bit confused about `If 2 cells next to the date are not blank` this line? Can you please clarify.

Comment: @Harun24hr I mean that in the array of data, if the cells meet the condition: has a value of date, equal to the condition AND the next 2 cells next to it should not be blank. 
Because my system returns the data like: date of events happened and  and 2 more variables next to it. If one variable not happened, we dont count it.
The problem is the data not stays consistently in just 3 columns, they appear randomly in an array with many colums. I need to count all of them.
I'm sorry if I dont make it clear.

Comment: @Harun24hr I left some comments in the file to make it clear. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
=COUNTIFS(H:H,F6,I:I,"<>""",J:J,"<>""")
```

put it in cell `G6` and drag downwards.. That should do..

<> means not equal to
"" means blank

(pls share if it works/not/understandable)

2nd formula (as per comment) :

```
=COUNTIFS(H:H,F6,I:I,"<>""",J:J,"<>""")+COUNTIFS(L:L,F6,M:M,"<>""",N:N,"<>""")+COUNTIFS(Q:Q,F6,R:R,"<>""",S:S,"<>""")
```

Comment: Ty for your help, but it's not actually what I need. Because the data I need to count it's not only in H I J but also spread in many columns.
The "data" means that it should come in group of 3, one is the date which should be match the condition (28Feb2023...) and the next 2 cells on the right of it will not be blank.
Ex: 
28Feb2023 ACB ABC should be counted as 1. 
1Feb2023 ABC ABC will not be counted
28Feb2023 (blank) ABC will not be counted
28Feb2023 ABC (blank) will not be counted.

Comment: yup..  that is exactly what the formula counts.. have a try.. | as u can see.. in only counts things in Column H I J. | To include same count in other column... do the 2nd formula (i just add) | also.. pls have a look at how countifs() works in https://exceljet.net/functions/countifs-function ..